# ArcGIS Autoincrement field for file geodatabase using domains

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, file-geodatabase

I have read this thread "[Autoincrement field when New Feature added](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58491/autoincrement-field-when-new-feature-added)" which suggests a python script to autoincrement a field.

Can anyone say if there is anyway to do this using domains or any other simpler way in a file geodatabase? I have to edit streets and would like to define a field which simply counts upwards.

For ArcGIS users that are not well versed in Python, scripts are pretty daunting, and having to run a tool every time an editing session is finished is also pretty inefficient.  It surely can´t be toooo difficult to have a new sequence-like data type in ArcGIS, can it?

Comment: What is your intended use of this autoincrement field once you have it?  Are you going to use it as a unique ID of some sort for joining purposes?

Comment: Most probably in the future, yes.

Comment: For the benefit of others, I am posting the link to the ArcGIS Idea that you created about this topic.  All, please visit the idea page and vote up to build some momentum behind this feature request.  [Create an Auto-Increment numeric data type for Geodatabase fields](https://c.na9.visual.force.com/apex/ideaView?id=087E000000056QUIAY)